# how C++ ranged based loops work internally

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to understand how C++ 11's for(type& x : ) (& stl's for_each) works internally and hoping someone can enlighten me. So the following code:

```
vector<int> v;
int z=0;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    v.push_back(z++);
for (int& i : v)
{
    printf(" %i", i);
    v.insert(v.begin(), z++);
}
```

prints 0 0 1 2 3.
I would understand 0 0 0 0 0 or 0 1 2 3 4, but that output, I can't quite understand how? What does for(x:y) compile to?? Don't think this will matter much, but I am using clang 3.4.

Thanks!

Comment: Your current code first inserts numbers, then iterates and inserts numbers. Is it intended? Remove the line `v.insert(v.begin(), z++);` from the second loop and try again. BTW. Why are you trying to modify a vector while looping over it? maybe you wanted to use std::list instead?

Comment: You're seeing UB, I believe.

Comment: std::vector::insert states besides other: "If the new size() is greater than capacity(), all iterators and references are invalidated.". The behavior is undefined.

Comment: @wonko: That's not actually the rule that matters here, having a large capacity won't save you.  The problem is that iterators after the insertion point are *always* invalidated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The C++11 Standard actually gives the equivalent traditional loop code, which is a pretty rare approach for Standardese.  You'll find it in section 6.5.4:

[image]

[image]

In the expansion, it's clear that the `end()` value from before the loop starts is saved and checked later.  Unfortunately, that iterator is invalidated by the first `insert()` call.  The rule on iterator invalidation:

> If no reallocation happens, all the iterators and references before the insertion point remain valid.

Clearly `end()` is not "before the insertion point".

Since the behavior of `insert(p, rv)` is "Inserts a copy of `rv` before `p`.", the insertion point is expressly *before* the iterator `p` (which is `v.begin()` here).  So the loop iterator `__begin` is also not "before the insertion point" on the first pass.

Comment: Screenshots from a render of the standard; novel! (You missed the closing brace)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: They're on a separate page, at least in my publicly available draft :(

Comment: Teehee  Also, unless space is reserved beforehand, `__end` is not the only problem: `__begin` will likely be invalidated too.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Ah yes, because "Inserts a copy of rv before p."  Always invalid on the first iteration, reserved capacity makes no difference.

Comment: Ah Thank you, apparently it was the behavior of insert that was messing my understanding up, not how for(x:y) is implemented...